# How do I programmatically change an MP3's cover art in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, image, mp3

I was wondering how I can change a downloaded MP3's cover art to a stored image. Is this possible? If so, where do I begin (I've tried looking it up on where/how to do it with no luck)?

Comment: Try to look for MP3 metadata, maybe something like http://id3.org/ID3v2Easy

Comment: So you can only do it through editing the metadata? If I have it at mp4 will this work? https://github.com/unixpickle/MP4Audio

Comment: Never done, but the only thing in the file besides the audio/video ans DRM I believe is the metadata, so the image might be there.

Comment: Since I believe that is the way, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look for MP3 metadata, maybe something like http://id3.org/ID3v2Easy

I believe the only thing in the file besides the audio/video and the metadata, so the image might be there.

But I believe it can be searched from another source based on the song author and title.